# In Blender, how can you dynamically generate a right prism between two parallel planes inscribed within an arbitrary closed polyhedron?

Tags: modifiers

I would like to flatten (scale to zero thickness in a specific direction), then solidify the result of a dynamic (un-applied) Boolean (difference) modifier, and see no obvious way to do this...

My ultimate goal with this is to generate a shape that is a variably thick slice of a dynamic volume, with perpendicular thickness, that does not extend beyond the bounding volume. Is there an easier way to do this?

---

if you collapse any closed convex polyhedron along any arbitrary axis, any part of the collapsed shape will have two polygons (a front and a back face) for all points within the flat shape... If the shape is concaved, you may have parts of the flattened shape with other even numbers of faces at some regions on the resulting flat shape. (You will see this as z-fighting as the shape is drawn on the computer.) I am unaware of a way in Blender to simplify such a shape to a set on non-overlapping faces.

[image]

[image]
(Thanks to @stacker for creating the wireframe that is much easier to see than my rendered image.)

The ring highlighted in orange in the wireframe image is actually the *negative space* **around** the slice that I'm trying to dynamically create. I included it in the .blend file to differentiate the shape I wanted from a simple Boolean intersection modifier.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a sketch of what you want to achieve?

Comment: This image is less clear than I hoped, but I think the .blend file will be easier to understand. The green slice is my intended result... the red strip around it is the difference between Suzanne and the thin rectangular prism... the rest of Suzanne and the prism are there in glass for context.

Comment: [image](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9667A48E2C8ED045!158&authkey=!AMGKl0vrthKUQEw&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng)
[ModifierSketch.blend](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9667A48E2C8ED045!159&authkey=!ADSzfkAAmDaH-3k&ithint=file%2cblend)

Comment: Notice that all sides of the green slice are normal (perpendicular) to the large faces of the prism. (It's not obvious from the model, but the green piece is the largest possible subset of the intersection with this property.)

@stacker , thanks for suggesting I post an image.

As far as srink-wrapping to a plane: This gives me the right "shape", except that it has excessive overlapping faces, which makes it useless for the solidify modifier. (a "scale" transformation is no better. :-( )

(Please excuse my multiple comments... this is my first question posted to StackExchange.)

Comment: @LorenOsborn After reading your question I had an idea of what steps could be required but had no idea of what you really want. This part of your comment above : "This gives me the right 'shape', except that it has excessive overlapping faces" could be the right question. Could you emphasize on this?

Comment: Let's see if I can better explain what I'm trying to describe:  if you collapse any closed convex polyhedron along any arbitrary axis, any part of the collapsed shape will have two polygons (a front and a back face) for all points within the flat shape... If the shape is concaved, you may have parts of the flattened shape with other even numbers of faces at some regions on the resulting flat shape. (You will see this as z-fighting as the shape is drawn on the computer.) I am unaware of a way in Blender to simplify such a shape to a set on non-overlapping faces.

Comment: You can use the solidify modifier effectively on a shape with no overlapping faces, but it produces odd results with overlapping faces, (at least from my experimentation.)

Comment: @stacker , forgot to tag you so you know I responded to your request

Comment: are you trying to animate or display a slice  of Suzanne like in MRI ?

Comment: @Chebhou , I just used Suzanne as a sample model. I'm working on a (currently) static model: I was hoping to use an animation bone or setting to allow me to modify the relative thickness of the flat sheets of material I build it out of. (Any ideas how to transfer the faces at a current setting to a paper cutout template for cutting out in the physical world would be appreciated. So far I've been making a template by UV mapping the pre-solidified faces to an image and fill painting them to distinguish the parts from the background.)

Comment: so if I understand correctly this is what are you trying to achieve : http://blogs.gre.ac.uk/architecture/2013/08/21/laser-cut-3d-sliced-models/

Comment: @Chebhou , In theory, yes... Something similar to the Slotted Slices on that page, bit this in an inner-support slice of a shape with mostly naturally flat outer faces. I want the extent of the support slice to dynamically adjust to the settable thickness of the walls around it.

Comment: sorry for the stupid questions but is this what you want : http://i.stack.imgur.com/sPTF1.png

Comment: @Chebhou , not exactly... That's why I specified "Slotted Slices" above; to differentiate it from the "Stacked Slices" at the top of the blog article you linked to. Also, this is within flat exterior faces not shown in either variation.

Comment: @Chebhou , if you look at the picture you posted, you'll notice that the edges of the slices aren't straight up and down, so it isn't a right prism.

Comment: check Suzanne in this [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/40064) , the width is variable by the solidify modifier, the edges are right angled the number of slices is controlled by the array

Comment: @Chebhou , because your slices are rather thin, this is a pretty good approximation, but breaks down with thicker slices. I will model the discrepancy as soon as I'm able, but it somewhat corresponds to sampling vs. integrating in calculus. Thank you for you suggestions and work putting this together. (It may have given me a couple ideas.)